# How to rotate item independently on each axis THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, quaternions

I have a 3D item that I want the user to be able to rotate with their mouse as they wish. I tried using 3 quaternions (one for each axis) and then multiplying them to get the final position of the item.

```js
// this.xQuat, this.yQuat, this.zQuat = new THREE.Quaternion()

rotate(e, axis) {
  // e.movement is mouse movement
  const dy = e.movementY

  switch(axis) {
    case 'x':
      this.xRot += dy / 100
      break;
    case 'y':
      this.yRot += dy / 100
      break;
    case 'z':
      this.zRot += dy / 100
      break;
  }

  this.xQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), this.xRot );
  this.yQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), this.yRot );
  this.zQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), this.zRot );

  // this.target is a THREE.Mesh()
  this.target.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(this.yQuat, this.xQuat);
  this.target.quaternion.multiply(this.zQuat)
}
```

However, this doesn't rotate the item independently on each axis, it rotates the axis themselves with the rotation of the item. I'm trying to keep the axis in place. so for example, if I want to perform a y rotation, I want to rotate the item around the world space y axis instead of the block's y axis.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I just figured it out 20 minutes later lol. Instead of multiplying all three quaternions every time the mouse is moved. I just multiplied the quaternion of the manipulated axis by the item's quaternion.

```js
rotate(e, axis){
        const dy = e.movementY
        
        if(axis != this.lastSelectedAxis){
            this.lastSelectedAxis = axis
            this.lastQuaternion.copy(this.target.quaternion)
            this.xRot = 0
            this.yRot = 0
            this.zRot = 0
        }

        switch(axis){
            case 'x':
                this.xRot += dy / 100
                break;
            case 'y':
                this.yRot += dy / 100
                break;
            case 'z':
                this.zRot += dy / 100
                break;
        }


        this.xQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), this.xRot );
        this.yQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), this.yRot );
        this.zQuat.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), this.zRot );

        switch(axis){
            case 'x':
                this.target.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(this.xQuat, this.lastQuaternion)
                break;
            case 'y':
                this.target.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(this.yQuat, this.lastQuaternion)
                break;
            case 'z':
                this.target.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(this.zQuat, this.lastQuaternion)
                break;
        }

    }
```